# git_merge error : 1 uncommitted change would be overwritten by merge when using libgit2 C library

Tags: git, libgit2

I am using libgit2 C version 0.22.0. Using that I am able to  execute git_remote_fetch & git_merge for first time. But when I am again trying to execute fetch + merge to update local repository files according to the latest commit which is available on remote repository the git_merge method throwing error message **1 uncommitted change would be overwritten by merge**.

Any idea why second time the same flow is not working? Do I need to create commit after first time when I am calling merge ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the message is quite clear: in your local repository you still have some **uncommitted changes** lying around; whence git doesn't want to merge. You need to either **commit**, **stash** or remove (`git checkout -- file`) those changes; then you can merge.

This problem has nothing to do with the libgit2; if you would do the exact same on command line; you would get the same outcome.